# Test Project cannot find project dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

A quick google of this question brings this solution

[Unit test project cannot find assembly under test (or dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993469/unit-test-project-cannot-find-assembly-under-test-or-dependencies)

But I have tried all the solutions in that question and none seemed to work.

I added a MSUnit Test Project to my already built program, and it cannot find any of the assembly references from the project.

Error looks like this

```
Could not load type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' from assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, 
Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

What I have tried

1. Add the project as a reference **not** as an assembly reference
2. Installed the NuGet Packages I depend on in the project for the test project. I noticed that all the dlls already exist in the bin folder for the Unit Test project.
3. Tried solutions such as restarting VS Studio, editing the configuration manager to ensure I am on the same platform(X64) as the project, look for the .accessor file to delete it (didn't find it), delete the test project and add it back.

None of this has worked.